# Variables in different methods together

Tags: java, class, variables

```
import java.util.*;

public class projectOneAdamYoung {
public static void main(String[] args){
  System.out.println("Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!");

  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
  String line = kb.nextLine();

  Scanner input = new Scanner(line);

  int redLight = 0;

  while(redLight != 1) {
  if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")){

     System.out.println("Thanks for using this calculator!");
     redLight = 1;

  }else {

     if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
        String numFirst = input.next();
        String opperator = input.next();
        String numSecond = input.next();
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(numFirst);
        double num2 = Double.parseDouble(numSecond);

           if (opperator.equals("+")) {
              calcAdd();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("*")) {
              calcMult();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("-")) {
              calcSub();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("/")) {
              calcDiv();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("^")) {
              calcExp();
           }

     }else {
        String opperator = input.next();
        String numFirst = input.next();
        double num1 = Double.parseDouble(numFirst);

           if (opperator.equals("|")) {
              calcAbs();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("v")) {
              calcSqrt();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("~")) {
              calcRound();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("s")) {
              calcSin();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("c")) {
              calcCos();
           }
           if (opperator.equals("t")) {
              calcTan();
           }
      }
  }
  }
  }

  public static void calcAdd() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
  }
  public static void calcSub() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + (num1 - num2));
  }
  public static void calcMult() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2));
  }
  public static void calcDiv() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + (num1 / num2));
  }
  public static void calcExp() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " ^ " + num2 + " = " + (pow(num1, num2)));
  }
  public static void calcAbs() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " | " + " = " + (abs(num1)));
  }
  public static void calcSqrt() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " v " + " = " + (sqrt(num1)));
  }
  public static void calcRound() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " ~ " + " = " + (round(num1)));
  }
  public static void calcSin() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " s " + " = " + (sin(num1)));
  }
  public static void calcCos() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " c " + " = " + (cos(num1)));
  }
  public static void calcTan() {
     System.out.println(num1 + " t " + " = " + (tan(num1)));
  }


}
```

I'm working on a calculator project for school, and need help.This is all my code and it doesn't compile because the variables I'm using to complete the operations are in a different Method. I can't figure out how to make this work looking at others' work.

Comment: What about using parameters in your methods?

Comment: What kind of parameters?

Comment: Uhm, `double num1, double num2` for the necessary methods?

Comment: I was gonna help but realized this code has just way too many problems. This goes to show you have NOT debugged this code even ONCE. I'm not going to re-write your homework assignment for you man.

Comment: I did not give you the answer, but instead provided you with links to material that will help you understand why you are running into problems and provided you with a short example that will help explain it some. This stuff is really something that you must learn in order to move forward with java or programming in general.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Luiggi's commentary **wholeheartedly** (but don't yet have the points to add to that thread directly).

Try invoking, for example, calcAdd like:

```
  calcAdd(num1, num2);
```

and defining it as:

```
  public static void calcAdd(double num1, double num2) {
     System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
  }
```

Verify that this fixes the compilation errors for calcAdd, then make similar fixes for calcSub, etc. It will take a few minutes of typing, but it will be a big step closer.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to read up on [passing parameters and accepting arguments](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html). Understanding variable [scope](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) is also important to learn. Until then, you can loosely use: What ever variable you declare inside of a set of `{` and `}` will be local to that area.

This example might help you understand a little more.

```
public class Pass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // variables to pass.
        // scope : everything inside of the main method.
        double one = 1.0;
        double two = 2.0;

        for (int a = 0; a < one; a++)
        {
            // scope of a = this for loop

            double three = 3.0; // variable three declared in this loop, scope = this loop.

            Pass.methodOne(one); // passing a parameter (double one) to methodOne.
            Pass.methodTwo(two); // passing a parameter (double two) to methodTwo.
        }

        // a = 2; This will not work because this isn't inside the scope of a.



    }

    static double c; // double c declared in class, scope whole class. 
                     // Note static keyword for access in static methods such as main.

    public static void methodOne(double d) { // accepting a parameter and calling it d

        //double d declared as argument variable, scope = this method.

        c = d; // local variable d is assigned to class variable c.

        System.out.println("The number methodOne received is " + c + ".");
    }

    public static void methodTwo(double d) { // accepting a parameter and calling it d

        c = d; // same c used in methodOne, different d.

        System.out.println("The number methodTwo received is " + c + ".");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;

public class ProjectOneAdamYoung {

private double num1;
private double num2;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ProjectOneAdamYoung().calculate();
}

public void calculate() {
    System.out.println("Welcome to the AP Computer Science calculator!!");

    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter an expression, or quit to exit: ");
    String line = kb.nextLine();

    Scanner input = new Scanner(line);

    int redLight = 0;

    while (redLight != 1) {
        if (line.equalsIgnoreCase("quit")) {

            System.out.println("Thanks for using this calculator!");
            redLight = 1;

        } else {

            if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                String numFirst = input.next();
                String opperator = input.next();
                String numSecond = input.next();
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(numFirst);
                num2 = Double.parseDouble(numSecond);

                if (opperator.equals("+")) {
                    calcAdd();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("*")) {
                    calcMult();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("-")) {
                    calcSub();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("/")) {
                    calcDiv();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("^")) {
                    calcExp();
                }

            } else {
                String opperator = input.next();
                String numFirst = input.next();
                num1 = Double.parseDouble(numFirst);

                if (opperator.equals("|")) {
                    calcAbs();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("v")) {
                    calcSqrt();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("~")) {
                    calcRound();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("s")) {
                    calcSin();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("c")) {
                    calcCos();
                }
                if (opperator.equals("t")) {
                    calcTan();
                }
            }
        }
        redLight = 1;
    }
}

public void calcAdd() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " + " + num2 + " = " + (num1 + num2));
}

public void calcSub() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " - " + num2 + " = " + (num1 - num2));
}

public void calcMult() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " * " + num2 + " = " + (num1 * num2));
}

public void calcDiv() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " / " + num2 + " = " + (num1 / num2));
}

public void calcExp() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " ^ " + num2 + " = " + (Math.pow(num1, num2)));
}

public void calcAbs() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " | " + " = " + (Math.abs(num1)));
}

public void calcSqrt() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " v " + " = " + (Math.sqrt(num1)));
}

public void calcRound() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " ~ " + " = " + (Math.round(num1)));
}

public void calcSin() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " s " + " = " + (Math.sin(num1)));
}

public void calcCos() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " c " + " = " + (Math.cos(num1)));
}

public void calcTan() {
    System.out.println(num1 + " t " + " = " + (Math.tan(num1)));
}
}
```

I changed your class just a little, to do what you wanted. But, that is not the better way to  do so.